# How to write following code with Conditional(Ternary) Operator?

Tags: java, conditional-operator, try-catch-finally

I am just playing with my code. The code in if else block can be written with conditional operator (? :).
how to write following code with Conditional Operator.

```
  import com.itextpdf.text.Document;

public class TEst {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Document doc=null;
        try{
         doc=new Document();
        //some operation.
        }catch(Exception e){

        }finally{
            doc!=null? doc.close():"";

            //if(doc!=null){
            //  doc.close();
            //}
        }
    }
```

*Eclipse suggestion :*

Multiple markers at this line

- Type mismatch: cannot convert from null to boolean
- Syntax error on token "!=", invalid AssignmentOperator

Comment: Does `doc.close()` return anything? If not, it can't be used in the ternary conditional operator.

Comment: also i´d consider using the `try-with-ressources` version here to close the `Document`.

Comment: Yes, close() is return boolean.

Comment: then you´d need to assign `doc.close()` to a boolean variable, and include something like `false` for the else part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the ternary operator here (using a dummy boolean and **not using** it again):

```
boolean dummy = doc != null ? doc.close() : false;
```

But i would highly recommend not using this kind of code. If you think a "1-liner" might be readable here consider doing something like:

```
if (doc!=null) doc.close();
```

**EDIT:**

Explanation why not to use this kind of code:

You would create a boolean which is never used again without gaining anything.

- The ternary operator is not faster than an if condition
- The code becomes unreadable in this case
- the boolean `dummy` still contains a boolean value if `doc` was `null`

Comment: But what is the use of that boolean ? :)

Comment: "But i would highly recommend not using this kind of code" I agree, but please explain why.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ there would be no use ;) It would just exist to be able to use the ternary operator

Answer (score 3):

No. Ternary operator can't be used this way.

```
//if(doc!=null){
    //  doc.close();
    //}
```

If you closely look the code commented, there is no else part at all. You just have only if and ternary operator needs an else for sure. Hence not possible.